# Translating SQL to Sqlalchemy Select with Join that Runs in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've looked high and low for examples of SQLAlechmy statements that use syntax like mine, but can't seem to find any, so here is my question.

The statement I ran in my database is:

```
SELECT register.username, rating, reviews 
FROM reviews 
JOIN register ON reviews.user_id = register.id 
JOIN books ON reviews.book_id = books.id
```

I use placeholders in my SQLAlchemy statements like so and want to continue with this syntax for this project.

```
books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = :id", {"id": book_id})
```

I tried translating the target SQL statement a few times, but can't seem to get the placeholders right. Here's the latest failed attempt.

```
db.execute("SELECT register.username, rating, reviews FROM reviews JOIN register ON reviews.user_id = :register.id \
    JOIN books ON reviews.book_id = :books.id", {"register.id": register_id}, {"books.id": book_id})
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

In an effort to solve the simpler problem and then scale up, I changed the query to the following:

```
db.execute("SELECT register.username, rating, reviews FROM reviews JOIN register ON reviews.user_id = :register.id", {"register.id": register_id}).fetchall()
```

The error message returned was . . .

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter 'register' [SQL: 'SELECT register.username, rating, reviews FROM reviews JOIN register ON reviews.user_id = %(register)s.id'] [parameters: [{'register.id': 7}]]
```

It wants to bind on `register`, which is a table. Experimenting with possible fixes.

Comment: Are you getting any error? I could see the placeholder for 'books.id' is misspelled as 'book.id'. Also, do you put placeholders ON join condition? It is weird. I have seen them only in 'Where' Clause.

Comment: What I'm doing doesn't actually demand a WHERE clause. Note that the following SQL statement produces the desired outcome: SELECT register.username, rating, reviews FROM reviews JOIN register ON reviews.user_id = register.id 
JOIN books ON reviews.book_id = books.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Key Takeaway:** When using placeholders in this manner, stay away from dot notation like `"register.id":` in your dictionaries. SQLAlchemy will try to bind a parameter to the name to the left of the dot.

While prior queries have all involved placeholders, and future queries will undoubtedly do the same, the winning query didn't need any (see below). This is the mistake of a SQL noob (to put it charitably).

```
reviews = db.execute("SELECT register.username, rating, reviews FROM reviews JOIN register ON reviews.user_id = register.id").fetchall()
```

To address the matter of placeholders, the following circumvented the error message mentioned in the above **EDIT**, but failed to return the desired results because the query was restricted to one `id`; I needed all matching user ids. Note how `"register.id"` became `id`. This was the decisive change.

```
reviews = db.execute("SELECT register.username, rating, reviews FROM reviews JOIN register ON reviews.user_id = :id", {"id": register_id}).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use placeholders in the WHERE clause and not in JOIN condition.

```
db.execute("SELECT register.username, rating, reviews FROM reviews 
JOIN register ON reviews.user_id = register.id 
JOIN books ON reviews.book_id = books.id 
WHERE register.id = :rid AND books.id = :bid", 
{"rid": register_id, "bid": book_id})
```

Comment: This is a really attractive query with intuitive appeal. Unfortunately, I get the error 'sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'dict'>'.

Comment: Thanks, As you suggested, naming the placeholder properly should solve the issue.

Comment: Also I made a change with the syntax, this query should work now without errors.